# Can I glue poly supply line to a connector?

Tags: plumbing, water, pipe, adhesive, sprinkler-system

I just bought a new house. The PVC connection to the foundation watering drip line snapped off because of ground movement. I bought several 1/2" parts (black) and connected the PVC back up to the existing drip line (brown). However, the connectors seemed to go on too easy and now they are leaking some.

[image: Pipe connections]

Can I glue these connectors in place? Or use a repair clamp?

Edit: I found another part of the brown drip line with [netafim](http://www.netafim.com/irrigation-systems-products#50475) stamped on it. All their parts are sized in mm, so this confirms my suspicions that the sizes don't match exactly.

Comment: Can you provide a picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used stainless steel pipe clamps and that fixed the leaks. Next time I will order the appropriate metric pieces from the original vendor. [image]

Comment: Basically, the rule of thumb is to always clamp polyethylene. A similar type is PEX which is always connected with compression fittings or clamps. The slick nature of this particular plastic defies glues and doesn't seem to lend itself to solvent welding like ABS/PVC.